# Clicking list item creates a new list item with the original list item's text content

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have 2 **ol**, on click of an **li** in the first **ol** I create an **li** in the second **ol**. I would like to set the text content of the newly created **li** with that of the first, clicked **li**. Example: 'item 1'.

Here's my JQ:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("li").click(function() {
        $(".secondlist").append('<li>placeholder</li>');
    });
});
```

Here's my [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/loteci/edit?html,css,js,output)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jQuery#append` and then declare a `text` variable equal to the text of the clicked list item. You will be appending this value.

```
$("li").click(function() {
    var current = $(this).text();
    $(".secondlist").append("<li>" + text + "</li>");
});
```

Here is the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vk80f7f5/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of this variants:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(".secondlist").append($(this).clone());
    //$(".secondlist").append('<li>' + $(this).html() + '</li>');
    //$(".secondlist").append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
  });
```

and if you will use `clone()` you may not use `'<li>' and '</li>'`